# replace-regexp: invalid use of \ in replacement text

Tags: regular-expressions

One of my collaborators has written a long rtf document that goes like this.

```
a paragraph of text

(1) some text

another paragraph or two of text

(2) some text

another paragraph or two of text
```

And so on. I've opened the file in emacs and I was trying to run `replace-regexp` to turn the parenthesized numbers into `\exx{` , where `\exx{` is a newcommand I have defined in the preamble and will take turn of sequential numbering. However, if I type

```
M-x replace-regexp ^([0-9]\{1,2\}) RET \exx\{ RET
```

Then I get the following error message

```
Invalid use of `\' in replacement text
```

I have tried using this alternative expression

```
M-x replace-regexp ^([0-9]\{1,2\}) RET \\\\exx\\{ RET
```

But this simply replaces `(1)` and subsequent numbers with `\\exx\{` , which is not what I want. Every other combination of backslashes that I have tried returns the `Invalid use of \ in replacement text` error.

I know I can use `sed` to get regexp replacement I want, but that is not the issue. I'm asking this question here because I want to understand how to do this particular type of regexp replacement internally to emacs.

Comment: Single escape: `\\exx\\{`

Comment: No, this replaces `(1)` with `\exx\{` , which is not what I want. I want the opening curly bracket without a preceding backslash.

Comment: Fine, `\\exx{`.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. To recap, my mistake was that I thought I had to escape the curly bracket as well in the replacement text

Comment: Your regexp seems to have an extra closing parenthesis. Is this also the case when you try it in Emacs, or is this a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: Now it doesn't have them anymore :) copy-paste error

Answer (score 7):

To make clear the accepted answer in the comments:

```
M-x replace-regexp ^([0-9]\{1,2\}) RET \exx\{ RET
                                           ^^
```

should be

```
M-x replace-regexp ^([0-9]\{1,2\}) RET \\exx{ RET
                                           ^
```

More generally, special symbols like `{`, `|`, `(` that need to be escaped in the regular expression search string, do *not* get escaped in the replacement string. Only '\' has to be.